# Set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS in Python project to use Google API

Tags: python, google-api

I am a programming beginner and thing I'm trying to learn how to use google API with `Python`.

I have:

1. created a project on Google Cloud and enabled the API that I want to use, `Natural Language API`.
2. created a credential and downloaded the credential JSON file, saved it as `apikey.JSON`
3. In the Terminal I have ran this command: export `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=apikey.JSON`, no error popped.

However, even when I ran the simplest of codes for this, I have errors which says the credential variable is not found.

I am not sure what to do now. Please kindly help.

**This is my code:**

```
from google.cloud import language

def sentiment_text(text):

    client = language.LanguageServiceClient()

    sentiment = client.analyze_sentiment(text).document_sentiment

    print('Score: {}'.format(sentiment.score))
    print('Magnitude: {}'.format(sentiment.magnitude))

sampletxt='Python is great'

sentiment_text(sampletxt)
```

**And I have errors:**

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/Users/YELI1/Downloads/googlecloud/sentimentanalysis/simple.py", line
> 21, in <module>
>     sentiment_text(sampletxt)
> 
>   File
> "/Users/YELI1/Downloads/googlecloud/sentimentanalysis/simple.py", line
> 5, in sentiment_text
>     client = language.LanguageServiceClient()
> 
>   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/gapic/language/v1/language_service_client.py",
> line 147, in __init__
>     ssl_credentials=ssl_credentials)
> 
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/gax/grpc.py",
> line 106, in create_stub
> 
>     credentials = _grpc_google_auth.get_default_credentials(scopes)   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/gax/_grpc_google_auth.py",
> line 62, in get_default_credentials
>     credentials, _ = google.auth.default(scopes=scopes)
> 
>   File
> "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/auth/_default.py", line
> 282, in default
> 
>     raise exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError(_HELP_MESSAGE) google.auth.exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError: Could not
> automatically determine credentials. Please set
> GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS or explicitly create credential and
> re-run the application. For more information, please see
> https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials.
```

The value is not in the environment

```
import os 
print(os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS']) 
   File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.2/Frameworks/Python.framework‌​/Versions/3.6/lib/py‌​thon3.6/os.py", line 669, in getitem  
raise KeyError(key) from None KeyError: 'GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'
```

Comment: May I see `print(os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'])`.

Comment: Code running 'import os
print(os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'])'

    Output
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/YELI1/Downloads/googlecloud/sentimentanalysis/simple.py", line 2, in <module>
    print(os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'])
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/os.py", line 669, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'

Comment: I dont know how to format this thing right, looks a mess, but looks like it is saying there is no such key of 'GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'. @stovfl

Comment: Yes, KeyError means the Requested Environment Variable is not set in the Environment of your Python Script. [Edit] your Question and add **OS Version, Python Version**. You must start the Python Script from the **same** Terminal you do the `export ...`.

Answer (score 278):

If you're working on a jupyter notebook and want to set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable in Python code :

```
import os
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"]="/path/to/file.json"
```

Comment: You can generate the credentials and the Json file by selecting your project on this link: https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/serviceaccounts

Comment: @marius thanks you, even google documentation was not clear

Comment: @Mim I think that "not clear" is an under-statement of dimensions!

Comment: How will you cater for this on production ?

Comment: @spaceofmiah in production, use a .env file with a line GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/path/to/file.json" and for example you can load this .env with a python lib like https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/ or other ways depending on the framework you use.

Comment: Pardon! doing *GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/path/to/file.json"* on production simply means i'll upload the json (which is advised against) and my .env. How is this possible when deploying to heroku without uploading your secret json file ?

> __Often in a self-hosted Node.js app, you use environment variables to contain sensitive information like private keys. Do not do this in Production__

Comment: @spaceofmiah Where did you read that bold line? Not here: https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#auth-cloud-implicit-python In heroku the config allow you to set var env and its the recommended way to do it in production. Maybe you can find additional help here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47446480/how-to-use-google-api-credentials-json-on-heroku

Comment: @Marius thanks for the links, will checkout on them.

Comment: THANK YOU. I was Googling for this error for so long and nothing worked.

Comment: Thank you. Pycharm can't recognize the environment variable of the system.

Comment: Automatically create .json file with this command:
gcloud auth application-default login

Comment: Thank you. This is more useful specially if you are only testing outside the main application's machine and this one already contains the setup in their environment variables.

Answer (score 37):

I know that this post was answered but the following is a cleaner way to specify the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` variable.

```
client = language.LanguageServiceClient.from_service_account_json("/path/to/file.json")
```

Comment: Yess, exactly! And this should be in the Google Translate API quickstart, too, not some environment variables, thanks @sdikby!

Comment: In 2021, this still isn't in the API quick start, thank you very much !

Answer (score 22):

There is 1 more simpler way of making it working by explicity mentioning Credentials and passing them to client as shown below.

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file("your-json-path-with-filename.json")
client = language.LanguageServiceClient(credentials=credentials)
```

Comment: Although this works, it means storing the file somewhere in the machine, which can be a vulnerability (in case someone takes over the machine), as discouraged here https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/

Answer (score 15):

In case you have the credentials in memory (environment variable for example), and you don't want to create a file especially for it:

```
from google.cloud import storage
from google.oauth2 import service_account

gcp_json_credentials_dict = json.loads(gcp_credentials_string)
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(gcp_json_credentials_dict)
client = storage.Client(project=gcp_json_credentials_dict['project_id'], credentials=credentials)
```

Using python3.7 and `google-cloud-storage==1.35.0`

Answer (score 9):

When your code is running in a local development environment, the best option is to use credentials associated with your Google Account.

1. [Install and initialize the gcloud CLI](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install), if you haven't already.
2. Create your credential file:

   ```
   gcloud auth application-default login
   ```

A login screen is displayed. After you log in, your credentials are stored in the local credential file used by ADC.  You should be then be allowed to automatically determine credentials.

Answer (score 3):

Another way to test this is to go into the terminal and type:

```
# Linux/Unix
set | grep GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
```

or

```
# Windows:
set | Select-String -Pattern GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
```

This will show you the environment variable and the path where it is located. If this returns nothing then you have not set the variable or you may have the wrong path set

Answer (score 0):

```
creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you edit your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Comment: I have a more complete example of the code above in my latest blog post: https://layer77.net/2023/08/15/migrating-from-oauth2client-to-google-auth-for-retrieving-google-adc-access-token-in-python/