# How to set Google Credentials to call Google API from Python app on Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, google-api

I have created a Python project with Flask and I uploaded it on `Heroku` as an app. The goal of this app is to identify the brand from a photo of a potato chips product/bag which is sent from the front-end. Specifically:

1. the front-end sends a photo of a potato chips product
2. the app on `Heroku` receives this photo
3. the app is calling `GCP Vision API` to retrieve information about this product (by using OCR etc)
4. the app is sending back the brand of the product at the front-end

The main python script which calls the `GCP Vision API` is the following:

```
from google.cloud import vision
from google.cloud.vision import types
import os

# For local
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = "/Users/User/PycharmProjects/Project_brand/Credentials.json"

brands = ['lays', 'pringles', 'ruffles', 'kettle']

def brand_detect(image):
    web, text = annotate(image)

    response_text = brand_text(text, brands)

    if (response_text is not None):

        return response_text

    else:

        response_web = brand_web(web, brands)

        if (response_web is not None):

            return response_web

        else:
            return 'Not Found'




def annotate(image):
    """Returns web annotations given the path to an image."""
    client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()

    image = types.Image(content=image)

    web_detection = client.web_detection(image=image).web_detection

    text_detection = client.document_text_detection(image=image)

    return web_detection, text_detection


def brand_web(web, brands):
    if web.web_entities:

        for entity in web.web_entities:

            for brand in brands:

                if (brand in entity.description.lower()) and (entity.score > 0.65):

                    return brand


def brand_text(text, brands):
    if text.full_text_annotation.text:

        for brand in brands:

            if (brand in text.full_text_annotation.text.lower()):
                return brand
```

The function `brand_detect()` is then called from the main `flask` function (which is written in another script within this app) so as to send the brand of the product to the front-end.

The `Credentials.json` file is inside the project's folder and it contains the credentials for calling the `GCP Vision API`. It looks like this:

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "**********************",
  "private_key_id": "**********************",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----**********************-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "**********************",
  "client_id": "**********************",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "**********************"
}
```

The app works fine locally with `PyCharm` but obviously I have to do some things more in order to call the `GCP Vision API` from my app on Heroku and do the same task. By this I mean, that the line `os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = "/Users/User/PycharmProjects/Project_brand/Credentials.json"` does not have any meaning/utility on Heroku so I have to modify my script above and do some things on Heroku so as to set Google Credentials and to call `GCP Vision API` from my python app on Heroku.

**Can someone explain me *step-by-step* how to modify my script above and what to do on Heroku in order to call the `GCP Vision API` on Heroku as I did it locally?**

Comment: What do you mean by `but obviously I have to do some things more in order to call the GCP Vision API on Heroku and do the same task`? You need to provide us with more information. What is the error you're getting? Do you just mean you have to switch to relative pathing for the location of your Google Credentials config file?

Comment: Thank you for your comment @Harrison. I have the impression that this path `/Users/User/PycharmProjects/Project_brand/Credentials.json` has no meaning for Heroku. Therefore, what should I do to inform my app on Heroku about the credentials? Shall I simply change the path to `Credentials.json` and then the json file will be identified on Heroku?

Comment: No. That path (the pycharm path) would not work for Heroku. Your Flask app is running on Heroku, not your local machine.

Comment: My `flask` script does not do anything more than calling the `brand_detect()` from the script above, getting the brand and sending it to the front-end. Therefore, if I am right, the question is how to modify the script above to call the GCP Vision API from the app on Heroku? In other words, because exactly the path above does not work for Heroku what should I do to make my app running on Heroku?

Comment: I found a solution that works for any language : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47446480/how-to-use-google-api-credentials-json-on-heroku?r=SearchResults

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to my problem was (surprisingly) very simple.

I had only to replace

```
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = "/Users/User/PycharmProjects/Project_brand/Credentials.json"
```

with

```
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = "Credentials.json"
```

and this works both for my app on Heroku and locally when the `Credentials.json` file is within the project/app folder.