# Flask app on Heroku cannot detect another file for authentication

Tags: python, heroku, google-api, google-oauth, dialogflow-es

I'm trying to create a webhook for Dialogflow that uses the Google Calendar API to set appointments.So the webhook is supposed to take the JSON request from DialogFlow, put into the Google API's required format and call the Google API. I'm using a server-to-server authentication for this.

My problems is that I keep getting an error 500("webhook called failed"). From the error logs it appears that it cannot find the JSON file which contains the authentication key. I don't understand why, because it's in the same Github repo which contains the webhook (it's called g_calendar2.py). The path inserted in the python file is the one I get when I open the JSON on Github and click 'copy path'. The authentication was fine when I ran it locally, though.

Anyone have any idea? Thanks!

g_calendar2.py

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account
import googleapiclient.discovery
import datetime
from httplib2 import Http
from oauth2client import file, client, tools
from flask import Flask, request, abort, make_response
import json 
import re 
import os


app=Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/webhook', methods=['POST'])

def webhook():

    req = request.get_json(silent=True, force=True)

    print(json.dumps(req, indent=4))

    res = processRequest(req)

    res = json.dumps(res, indent=4)

    r = make_response(res)

    r.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'

    return r

def processRequest(req):

    info=req.get("queryResult").get("parameters")

    datetime=info.get("date-time")

    data=datetime

    def getEmails(str):

        email_address=info.get("email")

        str = str(email_address)

        regex = r'([\w0-9._-]+@[\w0-9._-]+\.[\w0-9_-]+)'

        return re.findall(regex, str, re.M|re.I)

    emails=getEmails(str)


    SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar']

    SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = '**Reponamedummy**/**filenamedummy**.json'

    credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)

    service = googleapiclient.discovery.build('calendar', 'v3', credentials=credentials)

    event = {
        'start': {
        'dateTime': data,
        'timeZone': 'Asia/Kuala_Lumpur',
        },
        'end': {
        'dateTime': '2018-09-06T14:10:14+08:00',
        'timeZone': 'Asia/Kuala_Lumpur',
        },
        'attendees': 
         [{'email': str(emails[0])}]
        }
    response = service.events().insert(calendarId='ssar.developer@gmail.com', body=event).execute()
return 'Event has been created.'


if __name__ == '__main__':

    port = int(os.getenv('PORT', 5000))

    print("Starting app on port %d" % port)

    app.run(debug=False, port=port, host='0.0.0.0')
```

Error logs

```
    2018-08-31T08:20:19.704681+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up

    2018-08-31T08:21:04.742356+00:00 app[web.1]: {

    2018-08-31T08:21:04.742402+00:00 app[web.1]:     "responseId": "bd0ed761-466a-463a-b01f-41d664e4e5bf",

    2018-08-31T08:21:04.742404+00:00 app[web.1]:     "queryResult": {

    2018-08-31T08:21:04.742408+00:00 app[web.1]:         "queryText": "Slot for the 3rd of September, 3 p.m. samudrirao@gmail.com",

    2018-08-31T08:21:04.742409+00:00 app[web.1]:         "parameters": {

    2018-08-31T08:21:04.742411+00:00 app[web.1]:             "email": "samudrirao@gmail.com",

    2018-08-31T08:21:04.742413+00:00 app[web.1]:             "date": "",

    2018-08-31T08:21:04.742414+00:00 app[web.1]:             "date-time":          "2018-09-03T12:00:00+08:00"

    2018-08-31T08:21:04.742415+00:00 app[web.1]:         },

    2018-08-31T08:21:04.742417+00:00 app[web.1]:         "allRequiredParamsPresent": true,

    2018-08-31T08:21:04.742419+00:00 app[web.1]:         "fulfillmentText": "Alright, you want to book for this date and time?",

    2018-08-31T08:21:04.742420+00:00 app[web.1]:         "fulfillmentMessages": [

    2018-08-31T08:21:04.742421+00:00 app[web.1]:             {

    2018-08-31T08:21:04.742423+00:00 app[web.1]:                 "text": {

    2018-08-31T08:21:04.742424+00:00 app[web.1]:                     "text": [

    2018-08-31T08:21:04.742425+00:00 app[web.1]:                         "Alright, you want to book for this date and time?"

    2018-08-31T08:21:04.742426+00:00 app[web.1]:                     ]

    2018-08-31T08:21:04.742427+00:00 app[web.1]:                 }

    2018-08-31T08:21:04.742429+00:00 app[web.1]:             }

    2018-08-31T08:21:04.742430+00:00 app[web.1]:         ],

    2018-08-31T08:21:04.742431+00:00 app[web.1]:         "intent": {

    2018-08-31T08:21:04.742437+00:00 app[web.1]:             "name": "projects/linibot-9070f/agent/intents/5cb9cdd4-502c-4306-86a8-73e03e263d8f",

    2018-08-31T08:21:04.742438+00:00 app[web.1]:             "displayName": "Appointment Booking"

    2018-08-31T08:21:04.742439+00:00 app[web.1]:         },

    2018-08-31T08:21:04.742441+00:00 app[web.1]:         "intentDetectionConfidence": 1.0,

    2018-08-31T08:21:04.742442+00:00 app[web.1]:         "languageCode": "en"

    2018-08-31T08:21:04.742443+00:00 app[web.1]:     },

    2018-08-31T08:21:04.742444+00:00 app[web.1]:     "originalDetectIntentRequest": {

    2018-08-31T08:21:04.742445+00:00 app[web.1]:         "payload": {}

    2018-08-31T08:21:04.742446+00:00 app[web.1]:     },

    2018-08-31T08:21:04.742448+00:00 app[web.1]:     "session": "projects/linibot-9070f/agent/sessions/483fa518-f3ee-e3e3-805d-35187044d201"

    2018-08-31T08:21:04.742449+00:00 app[web.1]: }

    2018-08-31T08:21:04.744563+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-08-31 08:21:04,742] ERROR in app: Exception on /webhook [POST]

    2018-08-31T08:21:04.744566+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):

    2018-08-31T08:21:04.744567+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app

    2018-08-31T08:21:04.744568+00:00 app[web.1]:     response = self.full_dispatch_request()

    2018-08-31T08:21:04.744570+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request

    2018-08-31T08:21:04.744571+00:00 app[web.1]:     rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)

    2018-08-31T08:21:04.744572+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception

    2018-08-31T08:21:04.744573+00:00 app[web.1]:     reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)

    2018-08-31T08:21:04.744575+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 35, in reraise

    2018-08-31T08:21:04.744576+00:00 app[web.1]:     raise value

    2018-08-31T08:21:04.744577+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request

    2018-08-31T08:21:04.744579+00:00 app[web.1]:     rv = self.dispatch_request()

    2018-08-31T08:21:04.744580+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request

    2018-08-31T08:21:04.744581+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)

    2018-08-31T08:21:04.744582+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/g_calendar2.py", line 22, in webhook

    2018-08-31T08:21:04.744584+00:00 app[web.1]:     res = processRequest(req)

    2018-08-31T08:21:04.744585+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/g_calendar2.py", line 57, in processRequest

    2018-08-31T08:21:04.744586+00:00 app[web.1]:     credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)

    2018-08-31T08:21:04.744590+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/oauth2/service_account.py", line 209, in from_service_account_file

    2018-08-31T08:21:04.744591+00:00 app[web.1]:     filename, require=['client_email', 'token_uri'])

    2018-08-31T08:21:04.744597+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/auth/_service_account_info.py", line 71, in from_filename

    2018-08-31T08:21:04.744599+00:00 app[web.1]:     with io.open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as json_file:

    2018-08-31T08:21:04.744605+00:00 app[web.1]: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '**Reponamedummy**/**filenamedummy**.json'

    2018-08-31T08:21:04.745327+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.103.217.221 - - [31/Aug/2018:08:21:04 +0000] "POST /webhook HTTP/1.1" 500 291 "-" "Apache-HttpClient/4.5.4 (Java/1.8.0_181)"

    2018-08-31T08:21:04.743647+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/webhook" host=saloon-bot2.herokuapp.com request_id=676b00bc-5840-4c39-a5c2-b29ea62980bb fwd="35.193.216.215" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4ms status=500 bytes=456 protocol=https
```

Comment: I don't understand the reference to the Github path. The file is being deployed to Heroku along with your code, so you need the path on the server - relative to where your code is being run from.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50234541/how-to-set-google-credentials-to-call-google-api-from-python-app-on-heroku Referred to this

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, just realised that as well. The code was being run from a .py file on Github, hence the reference to a Github path. Anyway, have solved it and have a different problem now... but that's another story :)