# Why Google Cloud Storage isn't taking my GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable [HEROKU]?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, heroku, google-cloud-storage

I'm developing a POC website with Spring Boot to learn about GCP products, in specific Google Cloud Storage. The context is I am trying to save a profile picture when a user is registered.

From Google documentation, I can use

```
StorageOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();
```

to validate my credentials if I have GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS on my environment variables. The fact is, I do have GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS as an environment variable (I'm using Linux Mint) pointing to my .json file (that is valid because using the path method it works), but it always returns 401 UNAUTHORIZED from GCP lib.

After spending HOURS searching, just to make sure I run this command on terminal:

```
gcloud auth application-default login
```

The response from this command is:

```
The environment variable [GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS] is set to:
  [/home/<myuser>/<some_folder>/<myapplication>-<id>.json]
Credentials will still be generated to the default location:
  [/home/<myuser>/.config/gcloud/application_default_credentials.json]
To use these credentials, unset this environment variable before
running your application.

Do you want to continue (Y/n)?
```

After confirming and login with my browser, to my surprise it worked using **StorageOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();**

So I'm assuming that GCP takes credentials from application_default_credentials file instead of the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS env var.

**So on my local environment, it's working fine.** The problem is: This website is deployed on Heroku and I can't use the *path method* because I don't want to put this credentials on GitHub.
I already put the environment variables at Heroku and didn't work.
Already tried to use these buildpacks too:

```
https://github.com/elishaterada/heroku-google-application-credentials-buildpack
https://github.com/gerywahyunugraha/heroku-google-application-credentials-buildpack
```

but I can't get it to work when on Heroku Cloud. Someone knows a way I can make this run using the [12factor](https://12factor.net) rules, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to pass credentials you can do it via [environment variables](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#passing_variable), that in fact is the one you are mentioning. To do it in Linux you should use the below command

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="[PATH]"
```

Nevertheless, something to keep in mind is that this variable only applies to your current shell session, so if you open a new session, set the variable again.

On the other hand, another option for perform this task is passing credentials [using code](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#passing_code), and as you can see in the shared link you should use something like below.

```
GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(new FileInputStream(jsonPath))
        .createScoped(Lists.newArrayList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"));
  Storage storage = StorageOptions.newBuilder().setCredentials(credentials).build().getService();
```

Finally, in case you do not want to point the credentials inside of your applications's code, you can use [Cloud Key Management Service](https://cloud.google.com/security-key-management). I think that KMS is a good option for your case but at the end, you should make the decision.

Comment: I tried with the command export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS, I also put it on bashrc and zshrc profiles. In fact, I can see my env variable when using "printenv" on terminal, but GCP gives me 401 unauthorized when the json path is on environment variable. The only way I could make it work is using the login command, but I can't use login command while in cloud... On my Heroku environment variables I added these credentials too, but the same error occurs. And I'm not using GoogleCredentials.fromStream(<file_path_here>) just because I don't have the json file on Heroku, only the env var.

Comment: I wanted to use environment variables because makes code looks cleaner, more adjustable and easy to work with different environments and branches. I didn't know about this Cloud Key Management Service, I'll take a look and check if its good for this project. Thank you for helping me.

Comment: Just putting more details, I tried every command to make it work with environment variables, export with and without double quotes, putting it on bash profile, zsh profile, anything. The only thing that made it works on local environment is the gcloud login command. What I'm wondering is how I can make it work on Heroku using environment variables (without putting the credentials.json directly on github because this will be a public repository)

Comment: It seems like this is and issue related to Heroku. I have found some similar cases ( [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47446480/how-to-use-google-api-credentials-json-on-heroku) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50234541/how-to-set-google-credentials-to-call-google-api-from-python-app-on-heroku/50249614#50249614) ) . In addition, this other [link](https://simpleit.rocks/apis/google-cloud/using-google-cloud-with-heroku/) can be helpful to perform the task you want. Hoping this information helps you.

Comment: Thank you so much, Samuel! I already visited these links (in specific [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47446480/how-to-use-google-api-credentials-json-on-heroku) one but tried only some methods. The method that worked is from Chrisjan. Creating two heroku vars and a .profile that create a .json in runtime on every login (deploy). I'll answer this question with more details to keep it if someone needs. Thank you again, Samuel!