# How to handle the google service account json file during production in Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, service-accounts

I hard a problem on how to handle the service account JSON file. I was able to make it work by creating a `.env` file with `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` key pointing to the JSON file path.

But during production, **how can I hide it from something like committing it to Github, since the file holds confidential data and I don't want to expose them**.

Comment: What's the problem with `.gitignore`-ing it?

Comment: I can't ignore it because during production like deploying it to Heroku will not able to find the file

Comment: You can have a production branch (only and only) for Heroku, which doesn't `.gitignore` it, while other branches like `master` can ignore it. This way you can push non-production branches to GitHub without loss of confidentiality.

Comment: Is this the only way since I would like to deploy it from GitHub for every push automatically, which mean anything that is on that GitHub branch will be the exact copy sent to heroku

Comment: Use Heroku config vars then: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars

Comment: Please view this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47446480/how-to-use-google-api-credentials-json-on-heroku