# How to deploy a PHP Laravel app on Heroku with Google's credentials.json file?

Tags: php, laravel, heroku, google-sheets, credentials

I have a PHP Laravel API, connected with a Google Sheet to retrieve some data. For authentication as a Google Client, I received a **credentials.json** file that I put in a **storage/app/credentials** directory on my local machine, which I added to **.gitignore** to keep it out of version control. I Installed *Google Auth Library for PHP* and set the path to the **credentials.json** file as a variable called *GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS* in the project's **.env** file. So `$credential` below simply holds the path to the JSON file.

```
$credential = getenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS');

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName('Pricing Calculator');
$client->setScopes(Google_Service_Sheets::SPREADSHEETS);
$client->setAuthConfig($credential);
$client->setAccessType('offline');
```

With this, the API works in my local environment, but on production I keep getting back internal server error 500's. I added a buildpack https://github.com/elishaterada/heroku-google-application-credentials-buildpack.git to set **credentials.json** as a *GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS* Config Var and assigned **google-credentials.json** to *GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS*, but it seems the **credentials.json** file is still not configured correctly on the Heroku production server.

I have the feeling it should be working already, but it isn't. So I either lack essential knowledge or I missed some obvious mistake. Both is possible, but anyway... any help or insight would be much appreciated!

The Git repo is here: https://github.com/Spesm/pricing-calculator-api

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use Google API credentials json on Heroku?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47446480/how-to-use-google-api-credentials-json-on-heroku)

Comment: Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56818296/11551468)

Comment: Thanks guys! It's precisely the approach I've tried, but now I see a comment that states that this buildpack doesn't work. That might explain my troubles!

Comment: It's not working with either buildpack for me. `$credential` holds **google-credentials.json** on production. This should represent the path to the actual JSON file, if I understand correctly?

Comment: It seems that those buildpacks where you can upload the credentials.json file are not working as expected. I finally managed with Lepinsk's buildpack (https://github.com/lepinsk/heroku-google-cloud-buildpack.git), which requires all keys and values to be set as config vars in Heroku. It does do the job though, so lots of thanks for that!

Answer (score 0):

For documentation purposes, this is related to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47446480/how-to-use-google-api-credentials-json-on-heroku/56818296#comment104683286_56818296).

It seems that the buildpack used on the linked question is not working. The suggested alternative is to use [this buildpack instead](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/gerywahyunugraha/heroku-google-application-credentials-buildpack).