# Access json file heroku

Tags: json, heroku, deployment

I am trying to deploy my application with Heroku from my Github. 
I placed my dotenv values in the config vars but one value refer to a json file, that heroku can not access

```
GCS_KEYFILE = file.json
```

And this is the json :

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "",
  "private_key_id": "",
  "private_key": "=\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "",
  "client_id": "",
  "auth_uri": "",
  "token_uri": "",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "
}
```

How can I make heroku access the file?

**Update**

I tried the answer below, that didn't worked for me. In the config vars I tried to add the json. Now I get the following error message :

```
2020-04-14T14:40:53.370477+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Could not authenticate request
2020-04-14T14:40:53.370493+00:00 app[web.1]: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/app/{
type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "",
  "private_key_id": "",
  "private_key": "=\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "",
  "client_id": "",
  "auth_uri": "",
  "token_uri": "",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "
2020-04-14T14:40:53.370500+00:00 app[web.1]: at /app/node_modules/gcs-resumable-upload/build/src/index.js:235:19
2020-04-14T14:40:53.370501+00:00 app[web.1]: at /app/node_modules/google-auto-auth/index.js:27:9
2020-04-14T14:40:53.370501+00:00 app[web.1]: at /app/node_modules/google-auto-auth/index.js:233:9
```

This is the error message when I try the answer below :

```
Error: You have to specify credentials key file for Google Cloud Storage to work.
```

The code I try to deploy can be found [here](https://github.com/Roene/Dating-app-team)

Answer (score 0):

Heroku does not give you a filesystem so this is not trivial.
It looks there is a [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47446480/how-to-use-google-api-credentials-json-on-heroku) using heroku-google-application-credentials-buildpack, but I have solved this in a different way: I package my application in a Docker image (which includes the JSON file wherever it expects it) and push/deploy that to Heroku.

The json file (which includes sensitive information) is not on my code repository and it is only pushed inside the image when the image is built.

Hope this helps.