# Spring Boot + cloud API deployment on heroku

Tags: spring, spring-boot, heroku, deployment, cloud

I'm trying to deploy simple app provided by google:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/tree/master/vision/spring-framework on heroku.

I've already done what is suggested in this thread [How to use Google API credentials json on Heroku?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47446480/how-to-use-google-api-credentials-json-on-heroku). But still im getting error. Im not even sure if its google credentials error or something else. Just for the record app works locally.

Here's **pom.xml** file i've already made some changes so its not clone of github project

```
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <spring.version>2.3.4.RELEASE</spring.version>
  </properties>


  <parent>
    <groupId>com.google.cloud.samples</groupId>
    <artifactId>shared-configuration</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.20</version>
  </parent>

  <groupId>com.example.vision</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-framework</artifactId>
  <name>Spring Framework with Cloud Vision Sample</name>


  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-vision</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <mainClass>com.example.vision.Application</mainClass>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>repackage</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

**VisionController class**

```
/*
 * Copyright 2019 Google Inc.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

package com.example.vision;

import com.google.cloud.vision.v1.AnnotateImageResponse;
import com.google.cloud.vision.v1.EntityAnnotation;
import com.google.cloud.vision.v1.Feature.Type;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.cloud.gcp.vision.CloudVisionTemplate;
import org.springframework.core.io.ResourceLoader;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

/**
 * Code sample demonstrating Cloud Vision usage within the context of Spring Framework using Spring
 * Cloud GCP libraries. The sample is written as a Spring Boot application to demonstrate a
 * practical application of this usage.
 */
@RestController
public class VisionController {

  @Autowired private ResourceLoader resourceLoader;

  // [START spring_vision_autowire]
  @Autowired private CloudVisionTemplate cloudVisionTemplate;
  // [END spring_vision_autowire]

  /**
   * This method downloads an image from a URL and sends its contents to the Vision API for label
   * detection.
   *
   * @param imageUrl the URL of the image
   * @param map the model map to use
   * @return a string with the list of labels and percentage of certainty
   */
  @GetMapping("/extractLabels")
  public ModelAndView extractLabels(String imageUrl, ModelMap map) {
    // [START spring_vision_image_labelling]
    AnnotateImageResponse response =
        this.cloudVisionTemplate.analyzeImage(
            this.resourceLoader.getResource(imageUrl), Type.LABEL_DETECTION);

    Map<String, Float> imageLabels =
        response
            .getLabelAnnotationsList()
            .stream()
            .collect(
                Collectors.toMap(
                    EntityAnnotation::getDescription,
                    EntityAnnotation::getScore,
                    (u, v) -> {
                      throw new IllegalStateException(String.format("Duplicate key %s", u));
                    },
                    LinkedHashMap::new));
    // [END spring_vision_image_labelling]

    map.addAttribute("annotations", imageLabels);
    map.addAttribute("imageUrl", imageUrl);

    return new ModelAndView("result", map);
  }

  @GetMapping("/extractText")
  public String extractText(String imageUrl) {
    // [START spring_vision_text_extraction]
    String textFromImage =
        this.cloudVisionTemplate.extractTextFromImage(this.resourceLoader.getResource(imageUrl));
    return "Text from image: " + textFromImage;
    // [END spring_vision_text_extraction]
  }
}
```

Pastebin with logs https://pastebin.com/fqQU5S4y

Answer (score 0):

puedes intentar con el archivo de configuración de spring-boot y colocar esta configuración.

```
spring.cloud.gcp.credentials.location=classpath:archivoPermisos.json
spring.cloud.gcp.project-id=idproyecto
spring.cloud.gcp.vision.enabled=true
spring.cloud.gcp.core.enabled=true
```

Suerte.

Comment: Can you translate to english ?

Comment: Si tu documento esta en español y lo necesitas en ingles, lo que necesitas despues de aplicar OCR es el Cloud Traslate. hay un ejemplo justo en Gloogle Cloud esta es la URL. https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/handwriting?hl=es