# Still getting error after setting config vars for google credentials and using elishaterada/heroku-google-application-credentials-buildpack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, google-cloud-platform

I am using rails backend with google NLP entity analysis and I have set my config vars appropriately but I am still getting this error when attempting run my application.

```
RuntimeError (Unable to read the credential file specified by 
GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS: JSON::ParserError):
```

Thanks all.

I followed the answer provided by maxim below
[How to use Google API credentials json on Heroku?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47446480/how-to-use-google-api-credentials-json-on-heroku/56818296#56818296)

Solved!
this build pack is not working.

- elishaterada/heroku-google-application-credentials-buildpack

Working
-CLI command-
heroku create --buildpack https://github.com/gerywahyunugraha/heroku-google-application-credentials-buildpack.git

Comment: The error states that `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` is incorrect. What did you set it to?

Comment: I set it to a Value of: google-credentials.json. My understanding is the buildpack should generate a google-credentials.json and fill it with the contents of GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS.

Comment: Solved! Lesson in attention to detail and patience. In the link I provided above one of the answers has a comment with a link to a working buildpack. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Please, could you provide your solution as an answer?