# Using Environment Variables as Credentials on Heroku

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, heroku, credentials

I need to make the "google-credentials.json" file works on heroku it's working locally by putting the local path on my laptop but in heroku I don't know how to do it.

I search a lot, I found this solutions
[How to use Google API credentials json on Heroku?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47446480/how-to-use-google-api-credentials-json-on-heroku)
but I couldn't make it works maybe the solution is old or I did it wrong the solution is to:

> 1 - Declare your env variables from in Heroku dashboard The
> GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS variable is the content of service account
> credential JSON file as is. The GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS env
> variable in the string "google-credentials.json"

> 2 - Once variables are declared, add the builpack from command line :

```
$ heroku buildpacks:add https://github.com/elishaterada/heroku-google-application-credentials-buildpack
```

> 3 - Make a push. Update a tiny thing and push.

This is my vars and Buildpacks:
[image: This is my vars and Buildpacks]

This is the Error Logs:

```
2022-03-11T09:22:57.866153+00:00 app[worker.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2022-03-11T09:22:57.866234+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/Professor_Bot.py", line 102, in <module>
2022-03-11T09:22:57.866678+00:00 app[worker.1]:     cred_obj = firebase_admin.credentials.Certificate(os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'])
2022-03-11T09:22:57.866696+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/firebase_admin/credentials.py", line 83, in __init__
2022-03-11T09:22:57.866909+00:00 app[worker.1]:     with open(cert) as json_file:
2022-03-11T09:22:57.866987+00:00 app[worker.1]: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: "'google-credentials.json'"
2022-03-11T09:22:58.491014+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 1
2022-03-11T09:22:58.644442+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
```

This is the python code:

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import db
import json
import os


cred_obj = firebase_admin.credentials.Certificate(os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'])

default_app = firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred_obj, {
    'databaseURL': 'https://professorbot-325702-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/'})
ref = db.reference("/")
ref.set({
        'boxes':
            {
                'box001': {
                    'color': 'red',
                    'width': 1,
                    'height': 3,
                    'length': 2
                },
                'box002': {
                    'color': 'green',
                    'width': 1,
                    'height': 2,
                    'length': 3
                },
                'box003': {
                    'color': 'yellow',
                    'width': 3,
                    'height': 2,
                    'length': 1
                }
            }
        })
```

And I would someone can help me thanks a Lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks God I finally Solved this issue Instead of Using Environment Variables which have the credentials file name and the json credential script and then using Buildpack to Generate local path You Just need to Create New Json File then write the credentials script inside and finally pass the new Json File name as a parameter to the LoadCredentialsFile Function Like This:

```
firebase_credentials = {
  "type": "",
  "project_id": "",
  "private_key_id": "",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
      "client_email": "",
      "client_id": "",
      "auth_uri": "",
      "token_uri": "",
      "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "",
      "client_x509_cert_url": ""
    }
    with open("firebase_credentials.json", "w") as write_file:
        json.dump(firebase_credentials, write_file)
    cred_obj = firebase_admin.credentials.Certificate('firebase_credentials.json')
```

Comment: Best answer ever, I have been searching back and forth, but this is more secure, and you have controll to almost everything

Answer (score 1):

Instead of pasting whole credential json file in Config Vars, you can put each key value pair manually in those config vars and then access them in your python program using `os.environ.get(key, default)`.

For ex. If you have Config Var as follows: `name: abc`, `os.environ.get(name, "Not Available")` will return `abc` if name key exists otherwise "Not Available."

Other thing you can do is, make your json file public, manually download this file on your Heroku machine using curl command in Run section and then it'll be available locally to machine but I won't recommend this way. Config Vars are good.

Comment: Nice Idea @Yash But Certificate method takes json file as a parameter 
cred_obj = firebase_admin.credentials.Certificate("the json file path")1

And for the Second way how I could make the json file public to manually download

Comment: You can do it by uploading that file on github then click on raw button to get only file contents, copy that URL of raw file and run curl command in heroku run option. Once done, you can delete your temporary git repo where you uploaded this file.