# How to provide google api credentials for Django app deployed with heroku, using docker

Tags: django, firebase, docker, heroku

I am deploying my backend Django app using heroku via docker. I am authenticating my flutter front-end api calls to backend using firebase auth. On my local machine, I am storing the google auth json file and referring to those parameters using the following:

```
cred = credentials.Certificate("google_api_data.json")
initialize_app(cred)
```

The google_api_data.json file is in the same folder as that of Django project with along with manage.py. I have the json file in gitignore, so I guess that prevents it from being uploaded to heroku while building. Now my questions is: **is there a way to store the contents of json file in 'config vars' of heroku and access them? If yes, how will I access them in my local machine?** The reason I am confused is, the json file has not just one key-value pair but bunch of lines. Thank you in advance for your help!

Following is the json file for reference:

```
{
 "type": "service_account",
 "project_id": "xyz",
 "private_key_id": "xyz",
 "private_key": "xyz",
 "client_email": "xyz",
 "client_id": "xyz",
 "auth_uri":"xyz",
 "token_uri": "xyz",
 "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "xyz",
 "client_x509_cert_url": "xyz",
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick Google search got me this question as the first result:

[How to use Google API credentials json on Heroku?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47446480/how-to-use-google-api-credentials-json-on-heroku)

There are a couple of good answers in there. Beware of some of the older questions, as it seem from the comments they no longer work.

I would recommend trying out the ones not using the buildpack. Maybe take a look at some of these:

- [reads from environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62536750/9935343)
- [write a local file in
  `.profile`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63447691/9935343)
- [split out
  each individual
  property](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72530731/9935343)
- [using a
  prebuild script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63259498/9935343)

From a quick glance, I think the two last ones might be a bit more secure than the two first.