# How to initialize Google Cloud Storage with credentials

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am able to do the following from a file:

```
from google.cloud import storage
self.client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json('/Users/david/file-163219.json')
```

However, if I try and pass the credentials directly, I get an error:

```
credentials_dict = {
      "type": "service_account",
      "project_id": "asdf-163219",
      "private_key_id": "asdf2938492837498234",
}
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(credentials_dict)
self.client = storage.Client(credentials=credentials)
```

But then I get an error:

> google.auth.exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError: Could not automatically determine credentials. Please set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS or explicitly create credentials and re-run the application. For more information, please see https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials.

What would be the correct way to pass the credentials dict?

Comment: Did you follow the link?

Comment: @KlausD. yes -- it gives two options (which I've both been able to do successfully), export a variable and load it from the credentials filepath, but I would like to do it directly from the python/json dict.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the method `from_service_account_file` requires a path, you could use a temporary file. For instance:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from google.cloud import storage
from google.oauth2 import service_account
import json
import os
import tempfile
if __name__ == '__main__':
    jsonfile = u"""<HERE GOES THE CONTENT OF YOUR KEY JSON FILE.
    CONSIDER THAT THERE ARE BACKSLASHES WITHIN THE PRIVATE KEY
    THEREFORE USE AN EXTRA BACKSLASH. FOR INSTANCE: 
    -----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\\nSomeRandomText
    INSTEAD OF: 
    -----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nSomeRandomText"""
    fd, path = tempfile.mkstemp()
    try:
        with os.fdopen(fd, 'w') as tmp:
            tmp.write(jsonfile)
        credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(path)
        storage_client = storage.Client(credentials=credentials)
        bucket = storage_client.get_bucket("your-bucket")
        blobs = bucket.list_blobs()
        for blob in blobs:
            print(blob.name)
    finally:
        os.remove(path)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Right, that's understood. My question is how to do it NOT from a file but actually from the dict itself.

Comment: Check this comment for another answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/56107690/3463297

Answer (score 13):

While explicitly setting up the client credentials, it requires project, which the client acts on behalf of, to be passed while creating storage Client. If not passed, it falls back to the default inferred from the environment.

```
from google.cloud import storage
from google.oauth2 import service_account

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(credentials_dict)
client = storage.Client(project='project_id', credentials=credentials)
```

Comment: It looks like you can specify `None` for `project`.  I.e., `storage.Client(project=None, credentials=credentials)`.  According to the [docs](https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/client.html#google.cloud.storage.client.Client), the `project` is only used when creating topics (for notifications).

Answer (score 0):

After trying for a very long amount of time to use a `.env` file to safely store my GoogleCloud credentials I eventually understood why it wasn't working. I have not find a solution in any other dicussion and this is the reason why I am sharing it here.

In order to provide some context, I am trying to upload an image to a GoogleCloud bucket. I an initial version of my code I used directly a `.json` file. However, not being a safe option, I wanted to store my credentials in a `.env` file instead. At first glance it would be very easy, I simply had to use the function `load_dotenv` to retrieve the information in my secret file and after I could create a dictionary with the values:

```
credentials_dict = {
        'type': 'service_account',
        "project_id": os.getenv('PROJECT_ID'),
        "private_key_id": os.getenv('PRIVATE_KEY_ID'),
        "private_key": os.getenv('PRIVATE_KEY'),
        "client_email": os.getenv('CLIENT_EMAIL'),
        "client_id": os.getenv('CLIENT_ID'),
        "auth_uri": os.getenv('AUTH_URI'),
        "token_uri": os.getenv('TOKEN_URI'),
        "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": os.getenv('AUTH_PROVIDER'),
        "client_x509_cert_url": os.getenv('CLIENT'),
        "universe_domain": os.getenv('UNIVERSE_DOMAIN')
    }
```

Finally, to use my credentials, the function `service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(credentials_dict)` was supposed to be everything I needed. However I got the error message:

```
 raise ValueError(
ValueError: ('Could not deserialize key data. The data may be in an incorrect format, it may be encrypted with an unsupported algorithm, or it may be an unsupported key type (e.g. EC curves with explicit parameters).', [<OpenSSLError(code=503841036, lib=60, reason=524556, reason_text=unsupported)>])
```

Not being an expert I tryied to find a solution in stackoverflow, but I found nothing.

Eventually I realized that the issue was coming from the format of my `.env` file. For some parameters like `project_id`, `private_key_id` (everything except `private_key`) we should not use any quotes, not `'` or `"`. But for the private key we should use some `"`. To have an idea of what my `.env` document looks like, there you have a snap code.

```
#.env
PROJECT_ID=this-is-my-project
PRIVATE_KEY_ID=44ddd555.....55111111vvddaa
PRIVATE_KEY="-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY---the_actual_key....."
CLIENT_EMAIL=your_email@blabla.com
CLIENT_ID=123...45678
AUTH_URI=https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth
TOKEN_URI=https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token
AUTH_PROVIDER=https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs
CLIENT=https://www.googleapis.com/gserviceaccount.com
UNIVERSE_DOMAIN=googleapis.com
```

I hope this can help some readers!

Answer (score 0):

on top of fred's answer, I realize `os.getenv` would auto-escape back slash. For instance, the `\n` in PRIVATE_KEY would become `\\n`, thus lead to error:

```
ValueError: ('Could not deserialize key data. The data may be in an incorrect format, it may be encrypted with an unsupported algorithm, or it may be an unsupported key type (e.g. EC curves with explicit parameters).', [<OpenSSLError(code=503841036, lib=60, reason=524556, reason_text=unsupported)>])
```

one solution is as fred's suggested, use double quote for the env variable PRIVATE_KEY, while we could also use `os.getenv('PRIVATE_KEY').replace(r'\n', '\n')` to workaround if editing the env is not possible