# Connect google storage client python without creds.json

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

now to define Google storage client I'm using:

```
client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json('creds.json')
```

But I need to change client dynamically and prefer not deal with storing auth files to local fs.
So, is there some another way to connect by sending credentials as variable?
Something like for AWS and boto3:

```
iam_client = boto3.client(
            'iam',
            aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,
            aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY
            )
```

I guess, I miss something in docs and would be happy if someone point me where can I found this in docs.

Comment: You can use `storage.Client.from_service_account_info(x)`. X is the contents of creds.json. Note that the contents of creds.json is JSON. To store as an environment variable, base64 encode first and base64 decode before use.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but `type object 'Client' has no attribute 'from_service_account_info'`

Comment: Yes, it does. You have done something wrong. Here is a link to the source code that declares these functions: https://googleapis.dev/python/google-api-core/latest/auth.html I have used this function multiple times in combination with Secrets Manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use built-in methods, an option could be to create the constructor for the Client (Cloud Storage). In order to perform that actions these [two](https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/client.html) [links](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/google.oauth2.service_account.html) can be helpful.

Another possible [option](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#best_practices) in order to avoid store auth files locally is using environment variable pointing to credentials outside of your applications code such as Cloud Key Management Service. To have more context about this you can take a look at this [article](https://medium.com/google-cloud/gcs-kms-and-wrapped-secrets-e5bde6b0c859).

Comment: Thanks for tip. But for some reason it doesn't work as expected. When I use `client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json('creds.json')` everything works. But if I try `creds = Credentials.from_service_account_file('creds.json')` (it creates Credentials class fine) and after `client = storage.Client(credentials=creds)` I have an error: ` DefaultCredentialsError: Could not automatically determine credentials. Please set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS or explicitly create credentials and re-run the application.`

Comment: I am not sure how you are performing this but here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52808848/how-to-initialize-google-cloud-storage-with-credentials you can find a case with a similar issue. You can try it but if the issue persists, please share the code snipped you are using.