# Download files from bucket using Google Cloud Client Library for Python

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I tried using gsutil to download files in a bucket, but now would like to incorporate the download in a python script to automate the download process (for downloading specific days data). The following gsutil code worked fine.

`gsutil -m cp -r gs://gcp-public-data-goes-16/GLM-L2-LCFA/2019/001 C:\dloadFiles`

Using the storage client I have tried:

```
from google.cloud import storage
client = storage.Client()
with open('C:\dloadFiles') as file_obj:
     client.download_blob_to_file(
         'gs://gcp-public-data-goes-16/GLM-L2-LCFA/2019/001', file_obj)`
```

I get error "DefaultCredentialsError: Could not automatically determine credentials. Please set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS or explicitly create credentials and re-run the application. For more information, please see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started"

This is a publicly available bucket.

Comment: Have you read the docs of this library?

Comment: Try storage library and use Google cloud doc. You have examples to simply copy and paste! Welcome on GCP!

Comment: @ForceBru I have read the download_to_file(file_obj, client=None, start=None, end=None)[source]# syntax but am not sure if that is applicable for an entire bucket folder or just a file?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I have tried "Retrieve a bucket using a string" (https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/storage/client.html) but get an error. Is retrieve the same as download? If I use "Download a blob using a URI", is a blob considered a bucket folder?

Comment: 1) Stackoverlow is for programming questions. Please post your code and we will help you solve problems. 2) Your question shows little effort in the question to try and solve your problem. 3) Edit your question with code that you have written, what you expect and any error messages. Then we will try to help you. Otherwise your question will be downvoted and closed. This link will help you understand how to use StackOverflow correctly: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3):

You did not setup GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
Follow below link and setup credentials

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45501082/set-google-application-credentials-in-python-project-to-use-google-api](http://%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45501082/set-google-application-credentials-in-python-project-to-use-google-api)

After setting up credentials your code will work

Comment: You only need to setup the  GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS in no google environment (your computer, you onPrem VM,...). On GCP component, your default credential is always set.

Comment: I created a service account key and added the code os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"]="C:\dloadFiles\json\mykey.json". However I now get error: IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\dloadFiles'

Comment: open the file in write mode `w`.

Answer (score 0):

After authenticating with your GCP credentials, you will also need to run:

```
gcloud auth application-default
```

To authenticate your application SDKs, such as your Python client libraries. Then you will be able to interact with GCP services via Python.
Also, you are copying a whole load of files with your `gsutil` command and not just one as you're doing with `python`. So you probably want to `list_blobs` first and then iteratively download them to files.
Also check out `blob.download_to_file` save you some coding ([docs here](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/storage/blobs.html?highlight=blob#google.cloud.storage.blob.Blob.download_to_file)). With that you can send a blob to a filename directly, without opening the file first.

Answer (score 0):

First thing, turn off public on this bucket unless you really need the bucket to be public. For private access, you should use a service account (your code) or OAuth credentials.

If you are running this code in a Google Compute Service, credentials will be automatically discovered (ADC).

If you are running outside of Google Cloud, change this line:

```
client = storage.Client()
```

To this:

```
client = storage.Client().from_service_account_json('/full/path/to/service-account.json')
```

This line in your code is trying to open a directory. This is not correct. You need to specify a file name and not a directory name. You also need to specify write permission:

```
with open('C:\dloadFiles') as file_obj:
```

Change to

```
with open('c:/directory/myfilename', 'w')
```

Or for binary (data) files:

```
with open('c:/directory/myfilename', 'wb')
```

I am assuming that this path is a file blob and not a "simulated" folder on GCS. If this is a folder, you will need to change it to a file (storage object blob).

```
gs://gcp-public-data-goes-16/GLM-L2-LCFA/2019/001
```

Comment: I am not the owner of the bucket. This is data from NOAA, a govt organization. The folder (001) contains subfolders with hundreds of .nc files. Those are the files I am trying to download. I don't understand what the "myfilename" would be because I am downloading files to a directory not to a single file.

Comment: Then you will need to use different code that lists the contents of the directory and then download one file at a time. My answer shows you how to download one file. You will need to create new code that scans a directory.