# "Could not automatically determine credentials." error when using youtube API in python

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I am working with Sublime Text 3 for a project and I keep receiving these errors.

```
Could not automatically determine credentials. Please set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS or explicitly create credentials and re-run the application. For more information, please see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started
```

Code:

```
import os
import re
from datetime import timedelta
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

api_key = os.environ.get('YT_API_KEY')

youtube = build('youtube', 'v3', developerKey=api_key)

hours_pattern = re.compile(r'(\d+)H')
minutes_pattern = re.compile(r'(\d+)M')
seconds_pattern = re.compile(r'(\d+)S')

total_seconds = 0


nextPageToken = None
while True:
    pl_request = youtube.playlistItems().list(
        part='contentDetails',
        playlistId="PL-osiE80TeTt2d9bfVyTiXJA-UTHn6WwU",
        maxResults=50,
        pageToken=nextPageToken
    )

    pl_response = pl_request.execute()

    vid_ids = []
    for item in pl_response['items']:
        vid_ids.append(item['contentDetails']['videoId'])

    vid_request = youtube.videos().list(
        part="contentDetails",
        id=','.join(vid_ids)
    )

    vid_response = vid_request.execute()

    for item in vid_response['items']:
        duration = item['contentDetails']['duration']

        hours = hours_pattern.search(duration)
        minutes = minutes_pattern.search(duration)
        seconds = seconds_pattern.search(duration)

        hours = int(hours.group(1)) if hours else 0
        minutes = int(minutes.group(1)) if minutes else 0
        seconds = int(seconds.group(1)) if seconds else 0

        video_seconds = timedelta(
            hours=hours,
            minutes=minutes,
            seconds=seconds
        ).total_seconds()

        total_seconds += video_seconds

    nextPageToken = pl_response.get('nextPageToken')

    if not nextPageToken:
        break

total_seconds = int(total_seconds)

minutes, seconds = divmod(total_seconds, 60)
hours, minutes = divmod(minutes, 60)

print(f'{hours}:{minutes}:{seconds}')
```

Comment: I believe this has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45501082/set-google-application-credentials-in-python-project-to-use-google-api)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set GOOGLE\_APPLICATION\_CREDENTIALS in Python project to use Google API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45501082/set-google-application-credentials-in-python-project-to-use-google-api)

Comment: I am new to working with API's and I tried using the link you provided for help, but my code is still not working @SuperStormer

Comment: Saying `but my code is still not working` is not helpful. State exactly what is not working, error messages, etc. 1) Are you using the Google Cloud CLI (gcloud)? 2) Did you create and download a Google Cloud service account JSON file? 3) What configuration have you done? Show the exact steps in your question.

Comment: The Playlist that you reference in your code has a video that shows how to setup credentials for the YouTube API - video 140. Watch that video to understand how to setup authorization. youtube.com/playlist?list=PL-osiE80TeTt2d9bfVyTiXJA-UTHn6WwU