# Can someone else create Service account for me and pass me JSON key to set env variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, credentials

In order to run my code, I have to set `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` env variable (to resolve the issue similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45501082/set-google-application-credentials-in-python-project-to-use-google-api))

I am not able to create a service account for that specific project through GCP IAM & Admin. My question is:

1. should I request for access to be able to create a service account and then set the JSON key path
   OR
2. Can someone else with enough privileges create a service account for me and pass me the JSON key

Comment: Why cant you create your own service account key file exactly? you don't need any special permissions to create one.   Which api are you trying to access?

Comment: Using service account key file is a bad practice and required in only very few cases. If you can't create one, it's for a good reason. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Use the CLI to create default credentials. **gcloud auth application-default login**. Using the CLI, you do not need a service account JSON key file and do not need to set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS. https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/application-default/login

Comment: @Sana Is your issue resolved ? If yes, can you post the procedure you've followed as a solution or can you accept or upvote if the answer helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a service  account you need to have Service Account Admin Role (roles/iam.serviceAccountAdmin) or Create Service Accounts Role (roles/iam.serviceAccountCreator)  and the following [permissions](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#service-accounts-roles) on the project . To create a service account find the document [here](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts).

Please set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS or explicitly create credentials and re-run the application.
This is one of the ways to make it working locally, you need to set up key:

```
gcloud iam service-accounts keys create /path/to/keyfile.json --iam-account=<your service account>
```

Then you run your app with environment variable

`GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` set to /path/to/keyfile.json, like this e.g:

```
GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/path/to/keyfile.json blaze run /your/target.
```

Extending John hanley comment, Use the CLI to create default credentials. gcloud auth application-default login. Using the CLI, you do not need a service account JSON key file and do not need to set [GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS.](http://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/application-default/)