# Google Application Credentials Python (Jupyter Notebook)

Tags: python, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-api-python-client, service-accounts

I'm trying to start using Google Analytics API 4 as instructed with Python and Jupyter Notebook. I follow the instructions https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/quickstart-client-libraries and get to Step 3. Configure authentication

And then they write that you need to set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="[PATH]" I downloaded this file to my computer and added it to the project folder, but I can't get verified using the service account.

On github they write https://github.com/googleapis/python-analytics-data#installation that you need to use a virtual environment? Is it so? Will it work without it?

I am using service-account, not oauth 2.0

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set GOOGLE\_APPLICATION\_CREDENTIALS in Python project to use Google API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45501082/set-google-application-credentials-in-python-project-to-use-google-api)

Comment: What for me Natural Language API?

Comment: It doesnt matter which api you are using its the same.   Just set the env var to the location of your service account credentials file.

Comment: Reporting API v4 didn't need any Python virtual environments https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/service-py?hl=en

Comment: Can you please provide an example for Python 3 Jupyter Notebook for service account authentication. Because I have not yet found any answer that would help me. I started reading about environments https://www.twilio.com/blog/environment-variables-python and got even more confused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did. I'll tell you how it turns out for beginners:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/quickstart-client-libraries

- Click on the blue button Enable the Google Analytics Data API v1, a project is created, a service account is created in Google Cloud and the Google Analytics API is activated. Download JSON file
- After that, you need to add a service account in the GA4 resource
- Then you need to authenticate according to the method from here https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#setting_the_environment_variable
  This requires Passing credentials manually. Using the code in the article, the path to the json file on the computer is indicated

When trying to authenticate a service account, 403 GET storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/… will be issued: starting-account-smhpwtovr5jj @test-data-api-1654114095791.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.buckets.list access to the Google Cloud project.

To do this, you need to go to IAM and create a new role for the Owner or Storage Admin service account. After that, GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS finds and you can start installing the Data API library

Answer (score 1):

To be clear GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS is a `virtual environmental variable`.  This variable is used by many of the google client libraries to load the credentials for any of the APIs.  The question i have duplicated this as shows a number of ways to set it.

As you seem to still be a little unsure. Here is some additinal information.

As stated in the docs.

> An easy way to provide service account credentials is by setting the **GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable**, the API client will use the value of this variable to find the service account key JSON file.

You need to set an env var on your machine to the path of the service account key file.

[image]

There are a number of examples of how to do that.

- [Authenticating as a service accoun](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#auth-cloud-implicit-python)
- [Set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS in Python project to use Google API](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45501082/1841839)

Comment: GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS is a virtual environmental variable. - That is, I cannot use the Google Analytics API in the directory by default. Do I need to install a virtual environment with a separate category (catalog)?

Comment: no you just need to create a environmental variable.

Comment: I did that, but now I get this: Forbidden: 403 GET https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b?project=test-data-api-1654114095791&projection=noAcl&prettyPrint=false: starting-account-smhpwtovr5jj @test-data-api-1654114095791.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.buckets.list access to the Google Cloud project.

Comment: And when I click on the link, I get another error: {"error":{"code":401,"message":"Anonymous caller does not have storage.buckets.list access to the Google Cloud project.","errors" :[{"message":"Anonymous caller does not have storage.buckets.list access to the Google Cloud project.","domain":"global","reason":"required","locationType":"header" ,"location":"Authorization"}]}}

Comment: I thought you were using Google analytics why are you mixing storage bucket into it?  If your having issues with another api you should open a new question.

Comment: according to your link it is written https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#auth-cloud-implicit-python

You need to install the google-cloud package and automatically or manually set the key via storage_client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json('service_account.json')

Comment: To use the Google Analytics API 4 and a service account, you cannot do without Google Cloud. You didn't know it?

Comment: I have been part of the alpha and beta test for the Google analytics data api for two years.  I think you are confused.  Google apis service accounts are not the same as google cloud service accounts this is two different things.  Follow the quick start [API Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/quickstart-client-libraries) it has nothing to do with google cloud storage.

Comment: check my guide - only in this case, together with the service account and google cloud, it allows authentication. The method in the documentation is exactly about this and writes, not oAuth 2.0